# Gradient of the tangent to the curve

Tags: calculus

This is my first time seeing this question and I'm not sure on how to approach it.
How should i find the gradient of the tangent of the curve?

$\ x^3+2x^2y+y^2=4 $ at point(1,1)

Comment: Have you learned about implicit differentiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Using  implicit differentiation, $$3x^2+2x^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}+4xy+2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$$

As $(1,1)$ is a point on the given curve, set $x=y=1$

Comment: can you explain how did 4xy came about? thanks

Comment: @xid00, $$\dfrac{d(2x^2y)}{dx}=2x^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}+2y\dfrac{d(x^2)}{dx}=\cdots$$